# Native query stuck after adding "#pageable" parameter for spring-data-jpa:2.x.x.RELEASE

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project where I am using MySQL DB.

My user repository extends `JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer>`. Following method is stuck after I upgrade my spring boot version to 2.x.x:

```
@Query(value = "Select * from user \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

It was working fine on previous version *(2.0.0.M1)*. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "is stuck"? Do you get an exception? How does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: Question isn't clear. But pageable can work on "Select * from user". "\n#pageable\n" isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @byteHunt3r

```
@Query(value = "Select * from user", nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

It's working fine for me.